# Why companies send email with nested table structure?

Tags: html-table, html-email

I checked that many companies, such as facebook, send email with **nested table structure** as following.

*( I checked it through my gmail account )*

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Some Header Contents
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Main Contents 1
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Main Contents 2
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

1. Why do they form contents with `<table>` tag, not `<div>` or `<p>`?
2. Why do they using **nested structure** with repeated `<table>`?

Comment: Who knows what evil lurks in the mind of Zuckerberg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most email clients, including webmail clients, are (sometimes intentionally) pretty bad when it comes to CSS. So it's almost impossible to style an email in a way that it looks good, or at least similar, on all or most devices and clients.

One of the problems is positioning your content. So the only way to that is to use tables, like we used to on webpages before CSS came along. So emails (specifically newsletters) look pretty much the way webpages looked like 20 years ago.

With tables you have control over the width, the height, the number of table cells per row, cellspacing (in CSS: margin), cellpadding, borders, alignment of content and you can use empty fields as spacers.

And with tables, most of the time it's necessary to use nested tables to get the result you want. You usually would have a table for your coarse structure and inside it a table for each section before you even begin to add content which will probably need a table too. Impossible to read, difficult to write, ugly to maintain, but alas it's still the only way.